# Topic reading inside a callback

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[EDIT]

I have changed my question because I think what I am trying to do is bit different from what was explained here before.

I have a Callback and I need to read a different topic inside this callback. I don't know if it is possible, but I have to ensure that some part of the code is only executed if the other topic has a particular value.

Any case, I don't know if I can read a topic or execute a particular Callback while I am just executing one callback

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199250/topic-reading-inside-a-callback/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-10**:
What is addCallback? Do you want to make another subscription or just "do the same thing as a callback would have" - in the latter case: It's just a function that you can call.

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-12-10**:
I have changed the question because It was totally confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest having 2 separate callbacks. And the code that requires certain variable to be set is executed only if respective flags are true. Also, I'd suggest using mutex on flags to avoid any race conditions. For eg.

```
class A 
{
    bool flag;
    std::mutex m;
    void callback1(...)
    {
         //Set the flag
         m.lock();
         flag = true;
         m.unlock();
         .
         .
         .
    }
    void callback2(...)
    {
        //Use flag to check if you wanna execute the code
       m.lock();
       bool isFlagTrue = flag;
       m.unlock();
       if (isFlagTrue)
       {
             //Put your code here ...
       }
};
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.

**EDIT:**

As Kramer suggested in his comment below, only one callback happens at a time. So you don't have to use mutex unless you have multi-threaded node process.

---

Originally posted by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) with karma: 281 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-12-10**:
FYI: unless the node has multi-threaded spinning, there isn't a need for the mutex. When a node uses single-threaded spinning, only one callback executes at any time (see: [Callbacks Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning)).

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2014-12-11**:
You are correct. I'll add that as an edit to the answer. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

You can't know the order in which messages will be received, so callbacks should be robust to information from other topics. From my experience of ROS, the best way of doing that consist in having callbacks that store data in node's class attributes, so they are accessible from other callbacks. You should also check if the data you need is available (the attribute has a consistent value) or skip processing if not.
At most, callbacks should be independent from each other.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3